# How can I determine the translator of a wikisource work?

Tags: translation

I am considering putting together English/Spanish versions of a few Mark Twain books, such as "The Prince and the Pauper" which can be found [here](https://es.wikisource.org/wiki/El_pr%C3%ADncipe_y_el_mendigo).

However, I need to know who translated it into Spanish from English. How can that be determined? If it is given in the link above, I couldn't find it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the work on wikisource is labeled BY-SA. So essentially you are not required to list the translator if republishing.

It is surprising not to have a translator listed. One method may be to try to locate the actual translation to an actual edition. On Google Books, for example, you can browse here. https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwisyYXSwuTNAhWI4yYKHd2kCs8QPAgD#q=El+pr%C3%ADncipe+y+el+mendigo+mark+twain+book&hl=en&tbm=bks

Another possibility is to search on WorldCat for a physical copy of the book. Even if you don't try to obtain the book, WorldCat might give you metadata about the translator's name.

Some books simply aren't published with the translator's name. (I seem to recall that 1001 Arabian Nights has a public domain version without a translator's name).

For the record, Project Gutenberg doesn't list spanish translations of the book: https://www.gutenberg.org/browse/authors/t#a53

Comment: Since the translation is editable, perhaps it is a joint effort that has been translated by tens or hundreds of cats.